# Refresh Token And Access Token Change and after change repeat 401 unauthorized Requests Angular 8

Tags: angular

i'm using interceptor for detect 401 error from catchErrors

here is my interceptor
i'm using ngrx store for refresh Token , so the request done well but it never called the failure requests again , i see all issues in stackoverflow and all not working for me

```
@Injectable()
export class InterceptService implements HttpInterceptor {
    connected: boolean = false;
    subject: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    // for Refresh Token
    private isRefreshing = false;
    private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    constructor(
        private toastService: ToastService,
        private translate: TranslateService,
        private _store: Store<AppState>,
        private userLocalStorage: UserLocalStorageService,
        private route: Router
    ) {
    }
    intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let token: string = this.userLocalStorage.getToken();
        if (token) {
            request = request.clone({
                headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
            });
        }
        if (!token) {
            request = request.clone({
                headers: request.headers.set('Accept-Language', localStorage.getItem('language'))
            });
        }
        if (request.url.includes('Upload')) {
        } else {
            if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
                request = request.clone({
                    headers: request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                });
            }
            request = request.clone({
                headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    if (event.status === StatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
                    }
                }
                return event;
            }),
            catchError((errors: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (errors.status === StatusCodes.BADREQUEST) {
                    if ('validationErrors' in errors.error && errors.error.message === 'Validation errors')
                        this.toastService.showToast('top-end', '200px', errors.error.validationErrors[0], 'error');
                    else
                        this.toastService.showToast('top-end', '200px', errors.error.message, 'error');
                }
                if (errors.status === StatusCodes.NOTFOUND) {
                    this.toastService.showToast('top-end', '200px', this.translate.instant('TRANSLATOR.THEREISANERROR'), 'error');
                }
                if (errors.status === StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED) {
                    // calling refresh token api and if got success extracting token from response and calling failed api due to 401
                    if (errors.headers.has(ConstantsStrings.TokenExpired)) {
                        console.log('error');
                        console.log(this.isRefreshing);
                        this.handle401Error(request, next);
                    } else {
                        this.toastService.showToast('top-end', '200px', this.translate.instant('TRANSLATOR.YOUDONTHAVEPERMISSIONTODOTHIS'), 'error');
                        this.route.navigateByUrl(`${RouteStrings.error}${StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED}`);
                    }
                }
                if (errors.status === StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN) {
                    this.toastService.showToast('top-end', '200px', this.translate.instant('TRANSLATOR.YOUDONTHAVEPERMISSIONTODOTHIS'), 'error');
                    this.route.navigateByUrl(`${RouteStrings.error}${StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED}`);
                }
                return throwError(errors);
            }),
            retryWhen((errors) => errors.pipe(
                flatMap((error, index) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(request);
                    if (!error.status || error.status !== 401) {
                        return throwError(error);
                    }
                    if (index === 0) {
                        this.userLocalStorage.addToken(request, this.userLocalStorage.getToken())
                    } else {
                    }
                    return of(error).pipe(delay(7500));
                }),
                take(2)
            )),
        );
    }
    private handle401Error(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        if (!this.isRefreshing) {
            this.isRefreshing = true;
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);
            const data = new RefreshTokenModel();
            data.accessToken = this.userLocalStorage.getToken();
            data.refreshToken = this.userLocalStorage.getRefreshToken();
            this._store.dispatch(new RefreshTokenRequested({ refreshTokenData: data }));
            this._store.select(getRefreshToken).pipe(skipWhile(a => a.accessToken === undefined
                && a.refreshToken === undefined), switchMap(tokens => {
                    this.refreshTokenSubject.next(tokens.accessToken);
                    this.userLocalStorage.removeAccessTokenAndRefreshToken();
                    this.userLocalStorage.setAccessTokenAndRefreshToken(tokens.accessToken, tokens.refreshToken);
                    window.location.href = this.route.url;
                    return next.handle(this.userLocalStorage.addToken(req, tokens.accessToken));
                }),
                catchError(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    return throwError(error);
                })
                , finalize(() => {
                    this.isRefreshing = false;
                })).subscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

my code is return undefined but after i add returnWhen it work but i navigate to base url because my interceptor don't do repeat the failure requests again

Comment: You should move `retryWhen` prior to `catcherror`

Comment: retry when also get Observable of errors so i have control after catch the error , it works , but i get the failure with authorized also but the token is not refreshed in the failure repeated request , but it refreshed in localstorage

Comment: But you navigate in the `catchError` this will lead the problem you saying?

Comment: yes i redirect in catch error if token not expired , but if expired i go to handle 401 as you see in interceptor to refresh token , i used switchmap as i see all article and it doesn't help

Comment: I think i got your problem. You need to use `switchMap` indeed but not inside `handle401Error` method. You should make it in the main pipe. You should remove your 401 handling condition instead check it in `switchMap` operator. and if condition is met (unauthorized) you should switch to pipe that you select from store else you should continue with the previous context

Comment: ok i understand , thanks , i will try this again

Comment: i try your example but not working not working